# How to count DOM API calls?

Tags: javascript, performance, dom, extjs4.2, performancecounter

I have issue with performance. I've investigated my situation and understood that the issue is in a tons of DOM API calls. Now I'm trying to improve performance by joining all of possible calls.

Calls are in loops so I can't count actual result of my "improvements". Also there are a lot of hidden calls by framework (ExtJS 4.2.2).

So... The question is:

How can I count DOM API calls?

Thanks!

Comment: You could just use [the Performance tab in Chrome's Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/).

Answer (score 1):

There is a better way of measuring your performance improvements.

I agree with @Mike McCaughan, that Chrome Dev Tools is a good tool in that case.

Instead of counting a calls to different functions (which might be hundreds of thousands in a heavy single page application), you might want to measure the overall scripting time in the summary chart bar (Performance -> Summary) before and after your improvements.

That is something, which you can easily demonstrate to your client on a review at the end of a sprint.

See screenshot for more details.

[image: Performance summary chart bar]

If you need to refresh your knowledge on Chrome Dev Tools, try this [free course on CodeSchool](http://discover-devtools.codeschool.com/).

It is a bit outdated, but most of the concepts are still the same (some of them were just moved to different tabs and / or renamed).